# Docker build adding empty directories when specifying Dockerfile location?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running into an unexpected behavior in Docker when building an image using a Dockerfile from a subdirectory of the context I'm building from, ie:

```
docker build -t test -f build/docker/golang/Dockerfile .
```

For sanity, I've removed pretty much everything from the Dockerfile, except for the following:

```
FROM golang:1.12-alpine3.9 AS builder
RUN apk add tree
WORKDIR /build/dir
COPY . .
RUN tree -a
```

Then, with a `.dockerignore` of:

```
*
!cmd
!pkg
```

I run, and get the following output:

```
$ docker build --no-cache -f build/docker/golang/Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.75kB
Step 1/5 : FROM golang:1.12-alpine3.9 AS builder
 ---> d4953956cf1e
Step 2/5 : RUN apk add tree
 ---> Running in 20bbaf5ce5b9
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing tree (1.8.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 6 MiB in 16 packages
Removing intermediate container 20bbaf5ce5b9
 ---> f93961f78847
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /build/dir
 ---> Running in e8637288cf26
Removing intermediate container e8637288cf26
 ---> 90473d72f983
Step 4/5 : COPY . .
 ---> aeec506ba056
Step 5/5 : RUN tree -a
 ---> Running in fa652d2cdf65
.
├── build
│   └── docker
│       └── golang
├── cmd
│   ├── api
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── worker
│       └── main.go
└── pkg
    └── math
        ├── math.go
        └── math_test.go

8 directories, 4 files
Removing intermediate container fa652d2cdf65
 ---> ef761dfd7e4e
Successfully built ef761dfd7e4e
```

So, to my question: What gives with the empty, but existing `build/docker/golang` directories? I can put stuff in them, nothing comes through, the `Dockerfile` isn't there, yet the directories exist... empty.. taunting me.

This doesn't occur if I move the `Dockerfile` into the root of the project (ie, `docker build .`, but that doesn't actually fix my problem, and isn't an option for this projects needs.

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using? I tried the same command and all files are copied. May be something to do with permissions or the Docker version you are using may have bug.

Comment: Server & Client version 18.09.3

Comment: Tried with the same server and client version. It is working fine. Check if you have .dockerignore and the files or folders are not included in it.

Comment: As I commented, the dockerignore is as shown, I even replicated it barely. Just having the Dockerfile in subdirectories, they keep being added to the build, empty

Comment: @syntaqx have you solved your problem? I faced the same issue.